# Компилятор ругается на операторы

Tags: c++

Есть класс CStep4, в нем конструктор, в котором я передал переменные из других классов.
Не могу понять в чем ошибка с операторами " * ".

```
class CStep4 {
    public:
    double Xt1, Yt1, Ht1, Xt2, Yt2, Ht2;
    
    public:
    CStep4(CStep2 t1, CStep1 cos_bx, CStep1 cos_by, CStep1 cos_bh){
        Xt1= x + t1 * cos_bx; //подчеркнуто умножение
        Yt1= y + t1 * cos_by; //подчеркнуто умножение
        Ht1= h + t1 * cos_bh; //подчеркнуто умножение
    }

CStep2: 

    class CStep2: public CCoord {   
    public:
    static double a1, a2, a3, b1, b2 ,b3;
    CStep2(double cos_ax, double cos_ay, double cos_ah, double cos_bx, double cos_by, double cos_bh){
        a1 = cos_ah * cos_bx - cos_ax * cos_bh; 
        a2 = cos_ay * cos_bh - cos_ah * cos_by; 
        a3 = cos_ax * cos_by - cos_ay * cos_bx; 
        b1 = cos_ax * (h2 - h) - cos_ah * (x2 - x);
        b2 = cos_ah * (y2 - y) - cos_ay * (h2 - h);
        b3 = cos_ay * (x2 - x) - cos_ax * (y2 - y);
    }
    public:
    double t1 = -((a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3)/(pow(a1,2) + pow(a2,2) + pow(a3,3)));   


CStep1: 

    class CStep1 {
    public: 
    double cos_ax, cos_ay, cos_ah, cos_bx, cos_by, cos_bh;
    CStep1(double a_E1, double a_B1, double a_E2, double a_B2){ 
        cos_ax = cos(a_E1) * cos(a_B1);
        cos_ay = cos(a_E1) * sin(a_B1); 
        cos_ah = sin(a_E1);

        cos_bx = cos(a_E2) * cos(a_B2);
        cos_by = cos(a_E2) * sin(a_B2);
        cos_bh = sin(a_E2);
    }
    
};
```

Comment: `class CStep2` не умеет умножаться на `class CStep1`. А именно это вы в операции и делаете `t1 * cos_bx`

Comment: `CStep1 cos_bx` — это передача объекта класса `CStep1` с именем `cos_bx`, а вы хотите использовать поле `cos_bx`, класса `CStep1`. Передайте объект как (например) `CStep1 cstep1` и используйте его поля таким образом: `cstep1.cos_bx` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь не понятно - что такое `x, y, h`? Откуда они взялись? Видимо код приведен не полный.
Разве что только путем логического рассуждения можно понять что CStep2 наследует их от CCoord - `class CStep2: public CCoord`

```
class CStep4 {
    public:
    double Xt1, Yt1, Ht1, Xt2, Yt2, Ht2;
    
    public:
    CStep4(const CStep2& a, const CStep1& b)
    {
        Xt1= a.x + a.t1 * b.cos_bx;
        Yt1= a.y + a.t1 * b.cos_by;
        Ht1= a.h + a.t1 * b.cos_bh;
    }
}
```

Но возможно есть проблема. Вы никак не инициализируете эти переменные `x y h` в конструкторе `CStep2`. А по-идее вы должны вызвать конструктор базового класса и передать в него нужные параметры.

Comment: x, y, h берутся с еще одного класса. Мне уже помог коммент needKvas